# Detecting Android update versus new app when prior version did not store preferences

Tags: android, mobile, download, upgrade

This question has been asked before but the solutions were tested and did not work.

We have v1 of an app that never wrote any preferences or created any data files. We now have v2 which needs to perform special processing if this is an upgrade of a v1 user but does not do the processing if this is first time load. In other words, we are allowing original users of the app to use some functions that new users of the new version will not initially have available.

The prior solutions all seem to be based on v1 having touched some preferences that v2 can detect on startup the first time. We executed the code samples for v2 but they failed to determine that there was a prior version of the app that had run before.

We will end up implementing a solution for both Android and iOS but we can first focus on Android as more of our v1 users are on Android.

Open to all suggestions and we will try them out.